# remove bad attributes from xml via xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

i have some xml and i am trying to remove bad attributes that some other xslt add them.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><MYXML xmlns="http://someURL/MYXML" xmlns:role="http://someURL/role">
    <firstElement>
        <LANGUAGE>Spanish</LANGUAGE>
        <VOCABULARY>Spain</VOCABULARY>
    </firstElement>
    <External xmlns="" xmlns:myxml="http://someURL/MYXML">
        <EXTARData/>
        <AnotherElementData>
            <AnotherElement xmlns="http://someURL/AnotherElement"/>
        </AnotherElementData>
    </External>
</MYXML><!--checksum=A477829F524D170104E87187AD2869F5443DD079196B0EDCD5C6B9CFDD315232 version=1-->
```

i would like to rid off the "xmlns="" xmlns:myxml="http://someURL/MYXML"" without success.

my expected results is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><MYXML xmlns="http://someURL/MYXML" xmlns:role="http://someURL/role">
    <firstElement>
        <LANGUAGE>Spanish</LANGUAGE>
        <VOCABULARY>Spain</VOCABULARY>
    </firstElement>
    <External >
        <EXTARData/>
        <AnotherElementData>
            <AnotherElement xmlns="http://someURL/AnotherElement"/>
        </AnotherElementData>
    </External>
</MYXML><!--checksum=A477829F524D170104E87187AD2869F5443DD079196B0EDCD5C6B9CFDD315232 version=1-->
```

could someone help me with it?

Comment: `xmlns=""` is an undeclaration of the default namespace, `xmlns:myxml="http://someURL/MYXML"` is a namespace declaration. In terms of the XSLT data model these are no attributes. So how do you expect the result to look like, is the `External` element together with its children supposed to be in the namespace declared further up on the root with `xmlns="http://someURL/MYXML"`?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide code samples there, throwing them into comments does not ease our task to understand what you want to achieve. In your question edit you have now a snippet below the line "my expected results is" that shows `<External xmlns="" xmlns:myxml="http://someURL/MYXML">` which doesn't make sense given your previous line with 'like to rid off the "xmlns="" xmlns:myxml="http://someURL/MYXML"'.

Comment: sorry, fixed it... i missing between the existing one and the result one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you seem to want to transform the elements in no namespace to the namespace of the root element:

```
  <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() = '']">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri(/*)}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

That together with the identity transformation gives

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() = '']">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri(/*)}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and results in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaFX

```
<MYXML xmlns="http://someURL/MYXML" xmlns:role="http://someURL/role">
    <firstElement>
        <LANGUAGE>Spanish</LANGUAGE>
        <VOCABULARY>Spain</VOCABULARY>
    </firstElement>
    <External>
        <EXTARData />
        <AnotherElementData>
            <AnotherElement xmlns="http://someURL/AnotherElement" xmlns:myxml="http://someURL/MYXML" />
        </AnotherElementData>
    </External>
</MYXML><!--checksum=A477829F524D170104E87187AD2869F5443DD079196B0EDCD5C6B9CFDD315232 version=1-->
```

As you see, that is not quite the result you have shown as the identity transformation in XSLT 1 copies the namespace `xmlns:myxml="http://someURL/MYXML"` that was in scope for the `AnotherElement`.

That problem can be avoided easily with an XSLT 2 or 3 processor by using

see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaFX/1.

With an XSLT 1 processor you would need more effort to make sure the elements are copied without any namespaces:

```
  <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() = '']//*[namespace-uri() != '']">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Complete example is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() = '']">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri(/*)}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() = '']//*[namespace-uri() != '']">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaFX/2